# Content element hidden in default language should be visible in translation

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

Small problem with translated content in TYPO3 8.7.13:

Translation in connected mode. In default language there is one element hidden which should be visible in translation. In the backend it looks like it would be visible but in the frontend the element is missing. (The other way round there is no problem: when the element in default language is visible i can always hide it in the translation.)

My language configuration:

[sys_language_mode] = content_fallback
[sys_language_overlay] = hideNonTranslated 
Translation in connected mode (we use L10N-Manager)

Is there a possiblity to make the translated element visible in the foreign language even when the element in the default language is hidden?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if my informations are up to date, but when I had similar case in older TYPO3 versions there were no way to achieve that. The workaround which I've used was to change type type (`CType`) of content element to "Empty", which was custom content element prepared especially for such cases. It is possible also to change the type to "Plain HTML" and just leave the bodytext empty.

Comment: Nice idea :-) You are right, it should work: switching to an empty content element instead of hiding it.

Comment: @lisardo Can you clearly explain? Where it  should be changed?

Comment: is there another solution for newer typo3 versions? or does it even work out of the box?

Comment: It seems, that this issue still exists: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/94196